# how to run Gremlin queries on Neo4j-3.5

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am Currently using Neo4j community version-3.5 with cypher and bolt driver.
Now i want to change it to Gremlin and Tinkerpop.
Which version of Gremlin and tinkerpop supports querying on Neo4j-3.5

Comment: Are you sure you can actually query Neo4j with Gremlin?

Answer (score 0):

The steps needed when connecting to Neo4j using Apache TinkerPop Gremlin are documented at (1) and the source docs for the same are at (2).

(1) https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin

(2) https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/docs/src/reference/implementations-neo4j.asciidoc